# onmouseover and inline function using the 'this' object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseover

I have the following bit of code:

```
<div id="some_div" style="border: solid 1px red; width:50px; height: 50px;" 
onmouseover="(function(){$(this).css('background','green');})();"></div>
```

The function gets run just fine but it doesn't seem to be able to find the 'this'.
How can I make it so that it will know to self-reference?

(Yes, jquery is referenced in my code)

Comment: Why use an inline function? It makes more sense to separate it out (keep code separate from design).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you want to be using an anonymous function there. I think

```
<div id="some_div" style="border: solid 1px red; width:50px; height: 50px;" 
onmouseover="$(this).css('background','green');"></div>
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to wrap it up in an anonymous function, you can do this.

```
onmouseover="(function(that){$(that).css('background','green');})(this);"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be messed up because you're executing the function. Let's break this up a little.

If this was not inline, it would look like this:

```
onmouseover = (function(){
    $(this).css('background','green');
})();
```

Notice the () at the end? This means you're executing the code before the function gets assigned to onmouseover.

Try this instead:

`<div id="some_div" style="border: solid 1px red; width:50px; height: 50px;" 
onmouseover="$(this).css('background','green');"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

@matt you can do the same with css, just by using the `:hover` on the class.

```
.SomeDiv
{
    border: solid 1px red; 
    width:50px; 
    height: 50px;
    /*remove the below line if you like to keep the hover color*/
    background-color:white;
}

.SomeDiv:hover
{
    background-color:green;
}
```

and

```
<div id="some_div" class="SomeDiv"></div>
```

Comment: he probably doesn't want to remove the background on `mouseout`. (Atleast from his code snippet).

Comment: @Dogbert this is easy, you do not use the background-color on the .SomveDiv, only on hover.

Comment: if I hover in and out using your code, the green will go away. But op's original code will stay green.

Comment: @Dogbert remove one line as I comment on code, and the green will stay

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're using jQuery, why not do it all the way

```
$('#tag').hover(function() { $(this).css('background', 'green'); });
```

```
<div id="tag"> ... </div>
```